# Tell type of encryption if given both input and output strings

Tags: encryption, cryptography, cryptanalysis

I have the string `Thisisatest` that is encoded as `MDQ4MGFhMzRhYTNkYjM1OGIzN2NkZTJhYjZiNjUzMjY=` and I am trying to find out what encryption is used here. I think that the encoded string is base64 encoded so I run a base64 decode to take `0480aa34aa3db358b37cde2ab6b65326` but from that point on I don't know how to proceed to get the initial string... Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a (base64 encoded) MD5 hash, as the 32 character hex value suggests. You cannot recover plaintext from a MD5 hash, but you can use bruteforce to make hashes of different text and see if the hash matches:

`$ echo -n 'Thisisatest' | md5sum -
0480aa34aa3db358b37cde2ab6b65326  -
$ echo -n 'Thisisanothertest' | md5sum -
c7127540291d57c5afa566b791b085fb  -`